# Java client-server chat (server not receiving string)

Tags: java

trying to make a simple client server chat program. I've already go it so that the server reads a user input which is then sent to the client. the client then receives this and displays it. I then have the client reading the user input and sending it to the server however the server doesn't receive it. Heres my code:

Client:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


class client {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
         Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
         System.out.print("Waiting for server to respond... \n");

         while (!in.ready()) {}
         System.out.print("Received Message: ");
         System.out.println(in.readLine()); // Read one line and output it

         System.out.print("\n");
         //in.close();

         System.out.print("Message:");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
         String data2 = sc.nextLine();
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         System.out.print("Sending Message: '" + data2 + "'\n");
         out.print(data2);
         out.close();


      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



class server {


   public static void main(String args[]) {

      try {
         System.out.println("Waiting for client connection...");
         ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234);
         Socket skt = srvr.accept();
         System.out.println("Client has connected!\n");
         System.out.print("Message:");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
         String data = sc.nextLine();
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         System.out.print("Sending Message: '" + data + "'\n");
         out.print(data);

         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));


         while (!in.ready()) {out.close();}      
         System.out.print("Received Message: ");
         System.out.println(in.readLine()); // Read one line and output it
         System.out.print("\n");


         //in.close();

         //in.close();
         //out.close();
         //skt.close();
         //srvr.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Both the client and the server use the same code for send/receive so I don't understand why the server won't receive.

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

print() send the text but not a new line. Try println() instead.

readLine() on the server waits for a new line, which you are not sending.

BTW: I wouldn't test for `in.ready()` this is more likely to be confusing than useful IMHO.

Comment: Hi, I've changed the print() to println() and it still does the same thing.

Comment: I am guessing you didn't take out the loops which call in.ready(). ;)  When I take these out, it works.

Comment: Hmm. I've now taken out both loops however it doesn't send at all now!

Comment: It has something to do with the out.close() I think

Comment: I agree. After you close the output, nothing get sent. Using println() only and no in.ready() loops, it worked for me.